# Opening modal in cfc from button in cfm

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to open a modal in cfc through a button in cfm. here is what I have so far. What do I need to change?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="openModal" data-a="openmodal">Add</button>

$(document).on('click', '#openModal', function(){ 
                    var a= $(this).data('a');

                         $.ajax({
                          url:'components/index.cfc?method=doShowModal&a=' + a,

                          success:function(){
                             $("#myModal").modal('show');    
                          }
                    });
        });

<cffunction name="doShowModal" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="a" required="true" />


        <cfsavecontent variable="modal">
            modal will be here
        </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn modal />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Page requests to cfc's are a bad idea.  I suggest rethinking your approach.

Comment: Beyond not calling a cfc directly for layout I am not sure what your issue is.  Is there a specific problem you are having that you need help with?

Comment: Not recomended, but how about this,  `$("#myModal").load('components/index.cfc?method=doShowModal&a=' + a)`?